# Omron Servo throwing error 0x84 while test running

Tags: automation, plc, servo

**Update and answer** The mistake i've made is keeping the `Servo on` PIN 34 ON while trying to test run the servo on CX-Drive. after making Servo ON pin OFF and the problem Solved.

I'm using CP1H-XA PLC and Omron G series Servo. I've connected the servo from CX-Drive and initialized the drive and auto-tuned with load connected with low rigidity settings.It was smooth until I've encoutered an error. CX-Drive showing me an error

> Drive1:An error occured while preparing Test Run. (0x84). Please check: communications speed; Servo is ready; Servo is not used by others; and Parameters Torque limit input setting and Drive prohibited are not changed from their default values.

1. I've changed Torque limit and drive prohibited values to 2:Forward use Pn5e and Reverse use Pn5f
2. Pn5E and Pn5F values are 300 and 100 respectively.
3. Servo is in Ready condition and Pin 34 of CN1 is On.
4. Servo is not being used by any other process, i'm pretty sure of that 'cause servo is in ready and not giving servo busy input.
5. Communication speed(baud rate) is set to 9600 and I've tested it with 2400 bps to 57600 bps but no luck.

Can anyone know why it is giving such an error? Please let me know if have solution for that.

For PC Communication I've connected R88A-CCG002P2 Omron original cable and for PLC communication I've connected with same cable but used 9 pin D-type female to male connector. Servo Model is R88D-GT04H. and using RS232 Communication and on PLC connected with CP1W-CIF01.

Comment: Auto-tune isn't always reliable.  It could be that you are still hitting torque limits.  You might try monitoring the torque value, either in the PLC or directly in traces in CX-Drive to see if you are running near the limit before it shuts down.  Try easing off the PID settings and running at low speed with soft acceleration - see if it runs ok.  If yes, then you may have to manually tune the parameters.

Comment: It could also be a resonant vibration issue - one cheap tool I use is an audio spectrum analyzer app on my phone.  Just touch the phone to the motor load (a static part!) while it's running and see if you can see any obvious peaks.  Alternatively, a digital scope in FFT mode with a microphone works.  In either case, you should probably be able to hear with your ears if this is a problem (it'll be loud!).  You can add filters (in the motor parameters) at those frequencies as they can quickly cause feedback problems that spike your instantaneous torque over the limit.

Comment: A third alternative to option 1 is to just try running without the load attached - this should immediatly tell you if your tuning parameters are too aggressive.  If it runs fine without load then you've either got a PID parameter problem or your acceleration values are too demanding.

Comment: The thing is motor is not starting at all. I'm trying to run the motor using plc with pulse and direction mode using acc and cx-drive. Either way it is giving an error and not starting at all.

Comment: Sorry, you said "it was smooth" - I thought that meant the motor was running smoothly, until... the error.  Are you connected to the servopack in CX-Drive directly, or through the PLC?

Comment: i've tried connecting it to the plc and pc both. but no luck